# Dynamic View Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Is it possible to create view dynamically in oracle where column names are stored in table?

The arrangement is something like the following where a table named `COLUMN_DATA` contains column information and table `VALUE_DATA` contains corresponding values that needs to be populated.

```
TABLE_DATA
--------- ------------
 table_id  table_name
--------- ------------
 1         table1
 2         table2


COLUMN_DATA
----------- ---------- -------------
 column_id   table_id   column_name
----------- ---------- -------------
 1           1          col1
 2           1          col2
 3           1          col3
 4           2          col4
 5           2          col5


VALUE_DATA
----------- ----------- ---------- -------
 record_id   column_id   table_id   value
----------- ----------- ---------- -------
 1           1           1          val1
 1           2           1          val2
 1           3           1          val3
 2           4           2          val4
 2           5           2          val5
 1           1           3          val6
 1           2           3          val7
 1           3           3          val8
```

What I require is the following view/output:

```
TABLE1_VIEW
------ ------ ------
 col1   col2   col3
------ ------ ------
 val1   val2   val3
 val6   val7   val8
```

Can this  be achieved?

Comment: What is the business problem you are trying to solve?  You could write a procedure that creates a view using dynamic SQL.  You could write a pipelined table function that returns an AnyDataSet that is dynamic in nature.  The latter approach would be very, very complicated however.  The former would require calling the procedure any time you change data in the table.  I would seriously question the wisdom of going down this path, however.  It looks like you're trying to build an EAV data model.

Comment: If you're building your database so that it will be flexible and "generic" (a la the EAV data model that @JustinCave mentions), I highly, highly recommend that you read [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/) first. If that doesn't make you change your approach (if it's possible, like!), nothing will!

Comment: Yes, its called XML.

Comment: @JustinCave have been asked to look into the feasibility, myself not very clear why they want to go this way.
have tried using dynamic sql but not sure on how to populate values vertically.

Comment: @Boneist will show this link to my boss may be then he may let me relax :P

Comment: good luck! Whilst setting such a flexible system up might sound like a good idea in theory, when it comes to retrieving data in practice, it's a bloomin' nightmare! It's like the old saying: "There's fast, good and cheap, pick two!" You can have your code be fast (ie. performs well) and flexible (takes time and effort) or fast and cheap (won't be flexible) or flexible and cheap (won't be fast!). I sincerely hope your boss steers away from the approach you're investigating!

Comment: @Boneist, how about this ;-) http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/194115/